# Desktop streaming to Wowza server using ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg, video-streaming, flowplayer, wowza

Recently, I'm trying to utilize **ffmpeg** for streaming live desktop screen to a **Wowza**  media server.

I have partial success on the subject so far:

I've managed to record desktop screen using the UScreenCapture directx dshow filter, and I'm also able to send this record to the server.
However, when I'm trying to send the screen directly to the server, it fails every time. The player is buffering pretty slowly, and shows a blank screen when it's done (the counter keeps counting).

So, here are the working methods

for recording screen:

```
ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -r 25 -vcodec libx264 output.flv
```

and for streaming video:

```
ffmpeg -re -i <input_file_here> -map 0 -c copy -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://stream.server.xyz:52000?pkt_size=1024
```

And this is the code I'm using:

> ffmpeg -f dshow -i video="UScreenCapture" -s **width** x **height** -r **framerate** -vcodec libx264 -pix_fmt yuv420p -b:v **bitrate** -an -vbsf h264_mp4toannexb -f mpegts udp://**your.destination.url:PORTNUMBER**?pkt_size=**some_bytes**

As far as I can remember, it worked well before I upgraded wowza.

Some additional info:

- **OS:** win7 sp1 64bit
- **ffmpeg** N-49610-gc2dd5a1 (Zeranoe FFmpeg build 2013 Feb 5)
- **UScreenCapture:** x64 Edition Version 2.0.14
- **Wowza** 3.5.2 running on a Debian linux 2.6.32-5-amd64
- **Flowplayer:** 3.2.15

Looking trough the Wowza log files, something caught my attention. It seems when I'm streaming desktop screen, the server somhow gets uncomplete packets, but when I'm streaming a video file, the error doesn't occurs.

```
RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:24 - - - - - 152629.665 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:27 - - - - - 152632.782 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:31 - - - - - 152636.383 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:38 - - - - - 152643.484 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:47 - - - - - 152653.088 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:52 - - - - - 152657.587 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:26:56 - - - - - 152661.624 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
WARN server comment 2013-04-11 11:27:05 - - - - - 152670.805 - - - - - - - -RTPDePacketizerMPEGTS.handleRTPPacket: Incomplete packet: 1504:1472
```

What causes this error? Any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Can you show the output which FFmpeg is providing? Also use `-bsf:v` instead of `-vbsf`

Comment: Well, the problem has been solved.

It seems that the default(?) packet size for Wowza media server is **exactly 1316**, and it won't work with different values...

I had examined the official samples, and all of them were using this value. Maybe you can edit this attribute in the server's config files.

Otherwise, the command itself works fine, thanks for the suggestion, @Nick van Tilborg!